# Illegal string offset warning on setting PHP array element

Tags: php, arrays

I would try to setting an element of an array with the following code:

```
if (empty($table['keys'])){
    $table['keys']=array(
        'primary_key'=>array(
            'id'
        )
    );
}
```

But I get the 'illegal string offset...' warning. I also tried another array key, in case of the 'keys' index would be reserved keyword, but it makes the same error.

Comment: Does not give me any error at all... see https://eval.in/511929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $table appears to be a string. try this before your if-statement:

```
if(!is_array($table)) $table = [];
```

or if the change will only take place if $ tablet is an array

```
if(is_array($table)) {
  if(!array_key_exists('keys', $table)||empty($table['keys'])) {
    $table['keys']=array(
        'primary_key'=>array(
            'id'
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the variable at some modules is string, not an array. This caused the problem. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
if( empty($table['keys']) ){
 $table['keys'] = [
   'primary_key' => [
      'id' => ""
    ]
 ];
}
```